# MIPS lbu doesn't work unless program is run twice

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim, spim

Given the following code (`main.s`):

```
        .text  
        .globl main

main:
        lui $t0, 0x1000
        lbu $t1, 2($t0)

        .data 
        .byte 0
        .byte 0
        .byte 133
```

When executed with

```bash
cat << EOF | spim -bare -noexception
load "main.s"
run 0x400000
print \$9
EOF
```

SPIM yields `Reg 9 = 0x00000000 (0)`. However, when adding just one more `run`:

```bash
cat << EOF | spim -bare -noexception
load "main.s"
run 0x400000
run 0x400000
print \$9
EOF
```

SPIM suddenly yields the correct value of `Reg 9 = 0x00000085 (133)`. This also happens if `reinitialize` is ran before the second `run`, but the weird stdin piping doesn't allow for that.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using QtSpim, which, confusingly, has two bare machine options.

- The first is a single check box for `Bare Machine`

  - This option changes the location for `.data` (perhaps among other things) from 0x10010000 (default) to 0x10000000.
- The second is a push button for `Bare Machine` that reconfigures all the check box options.

  - It will select the `Bare Machine` check box, and also among the check boxes selected by the push button, is
  - `Enable Delayed Loads`.

I believe that `-bare` on Spim is the same as the push button on QtSpim, which includes both the "Bare Machine" `.data` location change, plus Delayed Loads and Delayed Branches.

Delayed loads is a aspect of the original MIPS processor and with it the results of any load instruction do not appear in the target register for an additional cycle/instruction.

So, since your program *ends* with a load instruction, and also is using the *Delayed Load* option, effectively, such program is *too short* to see the result of that final load operation.

Somehow those results do appear if you run again without reinitialization — while I cannot reproduce using QtSpim (there's no "run" command that can be used twice), it would appear that this second run you're doing provides that extra one cycle needed to finish the (first run's) load.

To fix so that you see the 133/0x85 in `$t1` on the first run, simply add one more instruction, e.g. `addu $0, $0, $0` — this additional instruction to follow that final load and cover the extra cycle needed by the load with delayed loads option.

A `nop` pseudo instruction would normally be an acceptable way to fill a delay slot, but with the `-bare` option (at least from QtSpim), the check box `Accept Pseudo Instructions` is disabled, so the `nop` pseudo instruction is not available, have to do it using a real instruction.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately, 1 `addu` still yielded the same behavior as in the question. I've also tested this on QtSpim with these settings: https://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-09/ass09_06.html, and the behavior is the same: `$t1 = 0` unless QtSpim is reinitialized once (Simulator > Reinitialize Simulator) and ran again (with the same play button), and then `$t1 = 133` as expected. Oddly enough, this is fixed with 2 `addu`s instead of 1.

Comment: As a side note, 2 `addu`s worked with `spim -bare -delayed_loads -nomapped_io -noexception`, but not `spim -delayed_loads -nomapped_io -noexception`, even though the second arguments mirror the usage message for `-bare` minus the pseudo-ops!

Comment: Ok, interesting, and a bit unexpected.  Well, looks like has something to do with delayed loads, can't guess further why your system and mine differ.